# How to parse link address from html tag

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
public void parse(){
    String x = "<p><a href=\"http://WWW.xxxx.COM\" class=\"url\" target=\"_blank\">Website for xxxx</a></p>";
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
        start++;
        if (x.charAt(i) == '\"'){
            start = i;
        }            
    }
    System.out.println(x.substring(start));
}
```

How can I remove tag from the string so I can get as final result:
`www.xxxx.com`

Comment: you want www.xxxx.com only? or with the http

Comment: yes, without http if it's possible

Comment: Would you also want to receive a warm cup of coffee while waiting for an answer? Oh, you can ask for a cookie too.

Comment: no, I am looking at a method on net. I am a beginner. thank you.

Comment: I think you want keep the substring "www.xxxx.com" from your content?

Answer (score 0):

Use replace method like this:

```
    String x = "<p><a href=\"http://WWW.xxxx.COM\" class=\"url\" target=\"_blank\">Website for xxxx</a></p>";
    String result = x.replaceAll(".*href=\"http://([^\"]*)\".*", "$1");
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: yes, a lot of thanks. Can you explain me the syntax of ".*href=\"http://([^\"]*)\".*", "$1"

Comment: .*href=\"http://([^\"]*)\".*
.* matches amy number of characters before href
href=\"http:// matches the href="http://
[^\"]* matches any characterss except / and " the brackets() tell ajva its a subgroup (represented by $1 that is the part that is matched here will be stored as $1 in replacement
\" matches "
.* matches any number of characters(of any type represented by .)
* in effect means any number of characters
. means any character
.* means any number of any type of characters

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this if you don't want to use regular expression.

```
    String x = "<p><a href=\"http://WWW.xxxx.COM\" class=\"url\" target=\"_blank\">Website for xxxx</a></p>";
    x = x.substring(x.indexOf("/") + 2); // or x = x.substring(x.indexOf("W"));
    x = x.substring(0, x.indexOf("\""));
    System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as shown below:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strYourText = "<p><a href=\"http://WWW.xxxx.COM\" class=\"url\" target=\"_blank\">Website for xxxx</a></p>";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"").matcher(strYourText);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```